# If error happens throw error else return the value

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

Try to send an HTTP request with parameter validation.

If the parameter validation fails, throw "parameter invalid" error and stop the following executions.

If the `code` of the API response doesn't equal `'0'`, throw `res.message` error else return the `res`.

I want to use `try...catch...` statements in the `main` function to catch any error mentioned above. And use the correct `res.result` in the `try` block.

```
import * as t from 'io-ts';
import * as T from 'fp-ts/lib/Task';
import * as TE from 'fp-ts/lib/TaskEither';
import * as E from 'fp-ts/lib/Either';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
import { failure } from 'io-ts/lib/PathReporter';

export interface ApiResponse<Result = any> {
    code: string;
    message: string | null;
    result: Result;
}

const GetArticlesByPageRequestDTOCodec = t.type({
    currentPage: t.number,
    pageSize: t.number,
})

type GetArticlesByPageRequestDTO = t.TypeOf<typeof GetArticlesByPageRequestDTOCodec>;

type GetArticlesByPageQueryPayload = {
    pagination: any;
};

const getArticlesByPage = async (data: GetArticlesByPageRequestDTO) => {
    return {
        code: '0',
        message: '',
        result: {
            resultList: [
                { id: 1, title: 'test' },
                { id: 2, title: 'test1' },
            ],
            totalItem: 100,
        },
    };
};

const getArticlesByPageTaskEither = (data: GetArticlesByPageRequestDTO) =>
    TE.tryCatch<Error, ApiResponse>(
        () =>
            getArticlesByPage(data).then((res) => {
                if (res.code !== '0') {
                    throw new Error(res.message);
                }
                return res;
            }),
        (reason) => new Error(String(reason)),
    );

const getArticlesByPageService = ({ pagination }: GetArticlesByPageQueryPayload) => {
    const reqDTO: GetArticlesByPageRequestDTO = {
        pageSize: pagination.pageSize,
        currentPage: pagination.current,
    };
    return pipe(
        reqDTO,
        GetArticlesByPageRequestDTOCodec.decode,
        E.mapLeft((errors) => {
            console.error(
                `Validation failed for input: ${JSON.stringify(reqDTO, null, 2)}. Error details: ${failure(errors).join('\n')}`,
            );
            return new Error('parameter invalid');
        }),
        TE.fromEither,
        TE.chain(getArticlesByPageTaskEither),
    )();
};

async function main() {
    try {
        const res = await getArticlesByPageService({ pagination: { current: 1, pageSize: 10 } });
        console.log(res.result)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

But the type of `res` is `E.Either<Error, ApiResponse<any>>`, so how to convert it to the `Promise<ApiResponse<any>>` type.

When I try to use `res.result`, got an error:

```bash
Property 'result' does not exist on type 'Either<Error, ApiResponse<any>>'.
  Property 'result' does not exist on type 'Left<Error>'
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM53gMyhEcDkwEAtDKvgNwBQoksiK6AKnNrgZmKagPQA2wAEY8maANaUa4aPCRo4TAKKscefJ278hI8YuAwAFgFMok2jIbzlbNRrJbhewybPT6AbzhhgYI3AC+KuzqXPYCwpgArgB2AMYwRNGudPCemMjAfJFQfoE2BESa4TwACsiGAEpGKS7UVEYAHilwwNEwJumxfgCC3lWokNGoRgA8-ZF88AC8KNEAngB8cO5UcGtwsRAAJkYAXHCoMFCtAObU63AgRqioyCd7B0encAA+cNETfOfrOagTMPtxpNqP4qFRNkN4ABxIwwbqwYCxPjXABCczK9yqAEdItcYAARJgAeQAwtsjLE4DMYAA6GBzXwAChWF1i2RybQxD1pHxAghMABpVuswHcjABlYAAL25NN5-KgQv8AEowfTfHAYXCEUjUeixdjcYdCUSqRgaUwGUYiZgRuqjBBMJrYfCErrUGiuYa8SayTtYgs6vbndq3ciPfr7gBFXFQfVzPgQZBbM0skV3VrlRL7ZDzEF1CGHOD3UOI8OesVmtBzOJwRlbcrIfZa11lvVeow4n3E5VUpZptY5GDZaLLYUXNabHb7fAABnwQon6yuNzFM4X44nv3++wHS5+13+ABlgId9gBtTf7ieeYBbfYARgFGH0yJn7UO+ACi+v+9v97gAAmZ8EhgN8CA-GAHy-fwf1-OAAF04N-GAIBgZA+AASXaEBH1nWdkIuWDN38fMwULeAS1bd0K3uURUDEJxjCgM160bZsXR1ctIyMb1jR7PtNyUOk4xJcpYgMEZFCgHBFTgXpgH6QZhgWRkr3WRleymBZ1KXKiuPbMU2PQ5U6WMaJGUZX4tP7XTf2AJ0rOuGkpz8ABCKYZjnfBez3eCl0MHAAHd3iMELpNkpzUBpFdbnuZVvn89ZQSSi4hxHOBfkS38VUIjScjQCBohs0Lwpk6BGXFJ5ohOJzCuK5VkIS8iiqLfSw0M+5xRMAA3RE-BmZkvAzaIsyKgIONLGieJjEx40TZMSr3CjMs7E1Juo7iOy7fjTRmPz0y66UHlFE5MwSIqaVOiVjryyd2SMTk12Gs7Rou6IXIetpkNIzd0qgUdvCZOycixE07pDTbOt4zsjQJYk-QpGl-XJCHFBi5AwCPIxMBgSyTFk1Alrs1lWogZEaQJiqSf3AADAA1DC7zG0d0kyIwU0waAWmiMBIgBOAABJ3AAKXFIkADkaUOY4aocuYnLB4lnw+Pg+GfQDlX8Gk4Ai7mdnQzJUH2YW2ayHJGSpqAiZpAArCBWkZfAAB0ki12mIYuZqkv+0dojC3XyqgJ3RSgZArnaFjWh6pmth87KiMauzhJsJjBWT9GJIyCz2rbCMuXoxj9GYpOvc0siqGrWsojid7LmzzSxwuI45ib-cVt+KsgoySjOI6-OxW6qA+q6IbTvO7Nlg2L6BafF6bplPCAgCb327JinE1q34aW3SZVSIjZxIMOsjF8uzC3JoxKaDy39+Sqh-CAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options. Firstly, you can just match on the `Either` in your main function

```js
async function main() {
  pipe(
    await getArticlesByPageService({
      pagination: { current: 1, pageSize: 10 },
    }),
    E.match(
      (e) => console.error(e),
      (res) => console.log(res.result)
    )
  );
}
```

Another option is to modify the `getArticlesByPageService` function to return `TE.TaskEither<Error, ApiResponse<any>>` instead of a promise (by simply removing the function evaluation at the very end of the function) and do something like this.

```js
async function main() {
  await pipe(
    getArticlesByPageService({
      pagination: { current: 1, pageSize: 10 },
    }),
    TE.orElseFirst((e) => TE.fromIO(Console.error(e))),
    TE.chainFirstIOK((res) => Console.log(res.result))
  )();
}
```

It is a good idea to perform side-effect only in `IO` or `Task` containers. Therefore, I'd personally prefere the that one.

Comment: I forgot to add you also need `import * as Console from "fp-ts/lib/Console";` import for the second example.